# grep -f with a here document

Tags: grep, heredoc, gnu-findutils

Here documents avoid creation of an intermediate, one-time use file. I was hoping to make use of this when getting the full paths of 20 possible files (without using `find -o` syntax). I expected the following to work:

```
find | grep -f <<EOF
Controller.java
Main.java
Config.java
EOF
```

but I get:

```
grep: option requires an argument -- f
```

Am I misunderstanding how here documents work? Or does grep -f not play nicely with file descriptors?

I'm also open to solutions with `find` that can take a list of `-name` values, but I don't want to have to type `-o` 20 times.

---

Best alternative:

```
cat <<EOF |  xargs --delimiter '\n' --max-args=1 -I% find -iname "*%*"
Controller.java
Main.java
Config.java
EOF
```

This is intellectually unsatisfying because you're running `find` on the entire file hierarchy once for each search pattern which won't scale well for large directory hierarchies.

Comment: Not totally following, but do you just want `grep -f-` where that tells grep to read a list of patterns from standard in?  You'd then also need to give it a list of files in the command string.

Comment: Hmmmm, it's related but I don't think I can pass it via stdin because I need the stdout of the `find` command to be the stdin to the `grep` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a system with /proc (eg linux), try:

```
#!/bin/sh

find . | grep -f /proc/self/fd/3 3<< EOF
Controller.java
Main.java
Config.java
EOF
```

Or, if your shell supports process substitution (Bourne Shell does not):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . | grep -f <( cat << EOF
Controller.java
Main.java
Config.java
EOF
)
```

Comment: The 2nd one is what I would consider the best solution. It works on Mac OS X (which doesn't have `/proc`). And process substitution is wonderful so it's worth forcing oneself of Bourne Shell (which I only use for scripting anyway, not interactive command line usage). I'm becoming a bigger fan of process substitution every day that passes.